# Should I add .vs10x to source control?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

After installed [VS10x Code Map](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2?SRC=Home) I found it created .vs10x files for all my projects.

I opened these files in Notepad and found they contain nothing but the following text:

> This file contains Alternate Data
>   Streams, storing configuration
>   information used by CodeSMART 10 and
>   VS10X Extensions.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT DELETE.

Should I add .vs10x to source control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mercurial [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658555/mercurial-and-ntfs-alternate-data-stream) alternate data streams, so you *could* check the file in, however I don't think you should since it is related to user-specific tool config information. Treat it like a .suo or .user file and ignore it.